# Cannot connect to ijavascript kernel / Cannot find module '../build/Release/zmq.node'

Tags: npm, jupyter, zeromq, ijavascript

I have a jupyterhub with jupyterlab / jupyter notebook installed.
I installed the ijavascript extension.
Launching jupyter notebook and opening a new notebook with a javascript kernel I get the message: "Kernel starting, please wait..."

At the console I get the following messages:

```
[I 15:22:24.145 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5),
new random ports internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/zmq.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/anaconda3/lib/node_modules/ijavascript/node_modules/zeromq/lib/index.js:6:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
```

My system is Ubuntu 18.4

I have "Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh" installed as root in "/opt/anaconda3".

Jupyter notebooks, jupyterlab and jupyterhub are running fine. The Python3 kernel notebooks are running perfectly and I could install several jupyter labextensions:

```
JupyterLab v0.35.4
Known labextensions:
   app dir: /opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
        @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v0.38.1  enabled  OK
        @jupyterlab/hub-extension v0.12.0  enabled  OK
        @jupyterlab/latex v0.6.1  enabled  OK
        @jupyterlab/plotly-extension v0.18.2  enabled  OK
        @jupyterlab/xkcd-extension v0.6.0  enabled  OK
        @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition v0.1.4  enabled  OK
        @lckr/jupyterlab_variableinspector v0.1.0  enabled  OK
        @mflevine/jupyterlab_html v0.1.4  enabled  OK
        jupyter-matplotlib v0.3.0  enabled  OK
        jupyterlab-drawio v0.5.0  enabled  OK
        jupyterlab_bokeh v0.6.3  enabled  OK
```

After having nodejs installed and adding proxy information in .npmrc (/etc/environment was already set) I could install the javascript kernel after I had nodejs installed:

```
conda install nodejs

conda install -c krinsman ijavascript

/opt/anaconda3/bin/npm install -g ijavascript
```

Somewhere on the line I tried
    /opt/anaconda3/bin/npm install -g zeromq

Since I received errors trying to install ijsinstall.

Finally I could install the kernel with:

```
/opt/anaconda3/bin/ijsinstall --spec-path=full --install=global
```

The kernel (links, entries and such) is available in the jupyter notebook as well as on the starter window of jupyterlab. However after a short while there is no connection with the kernel. ("No Kernel" showing in jupyterlab)
On the console I get the above mentioned error message (for juypter notebook):

```
Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/zmq.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
```

A

```
    find /opt/anaconda3 -name "zmq.node"
```

returns the following:

```
/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/ijavascript-v5.0.20-0/lib/node_modules/ijavascript/node_modules/zeromq/build/Release/zmq.node
/opt/anaconda3/lib/node_modules/zeromq/build/Release/zmq.node
```

Trying "ijskernel" gives the same error message as well as:

```
ijsnotebook --allow-root
```

Do I have to install ijavascript differently?
Do I have to copy/link zmq.node somewhere else?
Is running as root or running as a service the problem?

Running the following command in /opt/anaconda3:

```
grep --include=\*.js -rnw -e 'build/Release/zmq.node'
```

I found:

```
pkgs/ijavascript-v5.0.20-0/lib/node_modules/ijavascript/node_modules/zeromq/lib/index.js:6:  , zmq = require('../build/Release/zmq.node')
lib/node_modules/zeromq/lib/index.js:6:  , zmq = require('../build/Release/zmq.node')
lib/node_modules/ijavascript/node_modules/zeromq/lib/index.js:6:  , zmq = require('../build/Release/zmq.node')
```

while

```
find . -name "zmq.node"
```

found the following

```
./pkgs/ijavascript-v5.0.20-0/lib/node_modules/ijavascript/node_modules/zeromq/build/Release/zmq.node
./lib/node_modules/zeromq/build/Release/zmq.node
```

Uninstalling ijavascript and zermq and reinstalling and copying of zmq.node into the directory given by the error message changes the error message (trying ijskernel):

```
KERNEL: ARGV: [ '/opt/anaconda3/bin/node', '/opt/anaconda3/bin/ijskernel' ]
Usage: node kernel.js [--debug] [--hide-undefined] [--protocol=Major[.minor[.patch]]] [--session-working-dir=path] [--show-undefined] [--startup-script=path] connection_file
/opt/anaconda3/lib/node_modules/ijavascript/lib/kernel.js:190
        throw e;
        ^

Error: Error: missing connection_file
    at parseCommandArguments (/opt/anaconda3/lib/node_modules/ijavascript/lib/kernel.js:182:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/anaconda3/lib/node_modules/ijavascript/lib/kernel.js:46:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)

ijsnotebook --allow-root
```

or

```
jupyter notebook --allow-root
```

or

```
jupyter lab --allow-root
```

get a local notebook running which can connect to the javascript kernel.

This is not working via jupyterhub.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to boil down to:

https://github.com/n-riesco/ijavascript/issues/184

I could not figure out how I have to install zeromq though.